# Elementary word-search

Tags: no-computers, word-search

Here's a simple wordsearch:

[image]

...and the text version:

```
P O X A N T I M O N Y L I T I F
M R E P P O C A K R Y P T O N C
U T N D I D X O T H T H I N P G
I I O D I N E W R O T N M G P L
N U N T O N N U M S R U C A N D
I D A R M S T A D T I U M I M U
E S M H T U T C U D U R L S U I
T I U O M U I A A H M A O B I C
S L D D E F N N G H I N X M N B
N I J I K L A G A M N I Y E O O
I C P U Q V R S S M T U G R C U
E O V M W X H A Y T R M E C R O
W N F L U O R I N E E E N U I T
H O U G Z T J H A T R N G R Z K
L G E N E G O R D Y H A S Y F O
N I O B I U M M U N A H T N A L
```

I seem to have misplaced the word list shortly after creating this - not to worry!
I'm sure you'll have no trouble finding all <s>23</s> 22 words on your own.

Tell me please, **why did I choose these words in particular?**

(Please not use a word-search solver or any other computer tools)

**Edit:** Oops!! It turns out I left out a word while making this puzzle. The word

> `PHOSPHORUS`

should appear in the word search, but it does not. So, no need to try to find it, but you should still include it in the reasoning for why I chose these words

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with word searches. Can words follow diagonals/columns/rows.  How about reading them backwards? (or would this give away the answer?)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK yes words can go horizontally, vertically, diagonally, and can run both forwards and backwards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The words are all

> Chemical elements! (As indicated by the title: 'elementary')

And

> Theres one for every letter of the alphabet (given there is a element starting with that letter)
>
> J, Q and W don’t have any elements starting with those letters, so there are only 23 possible words hidden.

Heres the completed grid:

> [image]

And listing them (see [El-Guests answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99606/18250) for coordinates!):

> Alphabetical order:
>
> **A**ntimony
> **B**ismuth
> **C**opper
> **D**armstadtium
> **E**insteinium
> **F**luorine
> **G**ermanium
> **H**ydrogen
> **I**odine
> **J** -
> **K**rypton
> **L**anthanum
> **M**ercury
> **N**iobium
> **O**xygen
> **P** (accidentally left out of grid)
> **Q** -
> **R**hodium
> **S**ilicon
> **T**ungsten
> **U**ranium
> **V**anadium
> **W** -
> **X**enon
> **Y**ttrium
> **Z**irconium

Comment: Almost correct! I did accidentally leave out PHOSPHORUS while making the puzzle (see edit), but there is an element that starts with R still left in the puzzle. Good luck!

Comment: And it looks like I’ve been nipped to the answer — nice job, BG!

Comment: @El-Guest still +1! That was very close! I’m going to credit you for R too if you don’t mind, because I spent 10 mins looking for it and couldn’t find it :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil should I accept yours or El-Guest's answer? because he technically finished first but I like your completed grid image

Comment: Fun puzzle BryanC, and great answer @BeastlyGerbil! This was a nice one.

Comment: @BryanC probably down to you. Generally it is recommended to accept whoever gets the correct answer first and while I was technically first by 5 or so minutes, but El-Guest got Rhodium first so you can decide :)

Comment: Note that rot13(gurer'f nyfb n GVA (qbjajneq, pebffvat gur A va Ghatfgra naq gur V va Treznavhz)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman ooh good spot! I assume thats not intentional, but a little easter egg :P

Answer (score 5):

Using the top left corner as (1,1) and the bottom right corner as (16,16) — (row, column)

> Antimony (1,4) to (1,11) 
>  Bismuth (9,16) to (3,10) 
>  Copper (2,7) to (2,2) 
>  Darmstadtium (6,2) to (6,13) 
>  Einsteinium (12,1) to (2,1) 
>  Fluorine (13,3) to (13,10) 
>  Germanium (14,13) to (5,6) 
>  Hydrogen (15,11) to (15,4) 
>  Iodine (4,2) to (4,7) 
>  Krypton (2,9) to (2,15) 
>  Lanthanum (16,16) to (16,8) 
>  Mercury (9,14) to (15,14) 
>  Niobium (16,1) to (16,7) 
>  Oxygen (8,13) to (13,13) 
>  Rhodium (6,4) to (12,4) 
>  Silicon (7,2) to (13,2) 
>  Tungsten (7,5) to (14,12) 
>  Uranium (6,12) to (12,12) 
>  Vanadium (11,6) to (4,13) 
>  Xenon (1,3) to (5,3) 
>  Yttrium (2,11) to (8,11) 
>  Zirconium (14,15) to (6,15)

It looks like

> Except for a missing P, there’s an element for every starting letter here. PS: sorry for the formatting, this was just hand typed on mobile....

Comment: I switched halfway through my answer to mobile, and wow it’s so much slower :P Great answer though! Very close one and I really like the coordinate idea, linked your answer in mine :)

Comment: @El-Guest I accepted Beastly-Gerbil's answer because his had a better visual, and also did complete the majority of the puzzle. However you did find the last (rather difficult) word, which means you did technically complete the puzzle first! I hope you don't mind